# How do I write two conditions for the other field when filtering by one field without typing query in spring-data-jpa?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

1. 60   Category3   Description3
2. 59   Category2   Description2
3. 58   Category1   Description1

I get this result as a result of the following code.

```
Page<XEntity> findByParentIdAndNameContainingIgnoreCaseAndDescrContainingIgnoreCase(
          Long parentId, String name, String descr, Pageable pageReq);
```

I want to get results like this.

1. 60   Category3   Description3
2. 59   Category2   Description2
3. 58   Category1   Description1
4. 48   Category5

When I list the data registered as 'Test', the 'descr' field is not listed as empty. How do I list the empty or full descr field with the name 'Test'?
Can you do without typing @Query?

Comment: Can you clarify the issue here because it is unclear?  What is the expected result of your query?What is the actual result? *When I list the data registered as 'Test', the 'descr' field is not listed as empty'* - what does this mean?

Comment: I advised you to use a JPQL, instead of a method with a name so long. It isn't good coding practice.

Comment: As @EduardoEljaiek said, that method name it's so long, even you can use a DetachedCriteria that simplified the query conditions.

Comment: What is so bad about a @Query annotation? It allows you to improve on that horrible method name. It is based on JPA standard and is database independent.